# How to get dropdown value into .php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

I need to get selected dropdown value into my .php file, which is actually send mail file.

When i select one of 6 options from dropdown, i want selected option to be included into the mail as the "subject" of the email.

Here is my **HTML code**

```
<span class="custom-dropdown big">
    <select id="mounth" name="mounth">
        <option value="default">-- Domain name --</option>
        <option value="value1" rel="icon-temperature">value1</option>
        <option value="value2">value2</option>
        <option value="value3">value3</option>
        <option value="value4">value4</option>
        <option value="value5">value5</option>
        <option value="value6">value6</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="changeme" name="changeme" />
</span>
```

**POPUP EMAIL FORM**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="popup-moda">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span id="spanhide" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Us</h4>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="post" name="form" id="forms">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="domain" name="domain"></div>
                    <input required id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
                    <input required id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
                    <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                    <div id="success" style="color: blue;"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**Here is my JS code** which actually displays selected option, but only as text before sending email.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.popup').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#domain').html('<b>' + $('#mounth').val() + '</b>');
    $('#popup-moda').modal('show');
        return false;
});
});
```

**My PHP file**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

$to = 'example@example.com';
$subject = 'New Customer Enquiry';
$msg = <<<EMAIL
Subject: $subject
Message: $msg
From: $name
Email: $email
EMAIL;
$headers = 'From:' . $email;

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);   mail.

echo "Thank you for your email! We will reply as soon as possible."; 
}
else
{
echo "Invalid Email, please provide a correct email address.";
}

?>
```

**Thank you guys. Any input is appreciated!**

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `select` inside your `form` so the selected value is sent to server along with the rest of form parameters.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form" id="forms">
    <!-- ... -->
    <select id="mounth" name="mounth">
        <!-- options -->
    </select>
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Then in your php file:

```
$subject = $_POST['mounth'];
```

And then use it in the subject.

**EDIT:**

Then you can add a hidden input to your form with that name and add the dropdown's value to it upon selection:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form" id="forms">
    <!-- form stuff -->
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenMounth" name="mounth" value="" />
</form>
```

And then listen to `select`'s `onchange`:

```
$('#mounth').on('change', function() {
    $('#hiddenMounth').val($(this).val());
});
```

And then in your php:

```
$subject = $_POST['mounth'];
```

Comment: OP needs to replace `$subject = 'New Customer Enquiry';` with `$subject = $_POST['mounth'];` and not `$selectedValue = $_POST['mounth'];`. They might not seem to know what to do here, given their experience.

Comment: It's not working. It's probably because contact is a pop-up thing and it only appears after i select from dropdown. If i put select inside my form, dropdown dissapears from the page.

Comment: @fox see the edit, you can add a hidden input to your form which holds the selected value and pass it to your server.